# What is difference between "projects.locations.templates.create" and "projects.locations.templates.launch" of Dataflow REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to start a Dataflow job based on a Dataflow template from Cloud Scheduler.

The document below mentions the API projects.templates.launch to start a Dataflow job:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates

The API document says this API "Launch a template.":
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch

But I found the other REST API projects.templates.create, and it works fine for me to start a Dataflow job from a Google-provided template:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/create

And the API document says this API "Creates a Cloud Dataflow job from a template."

For me, the two API descriptions look the same.
Does anyone know the difference of two APIs?

Comment: Hi @mkk, there is a missing char in lauch url. Also looking at this documentation they didn't retrun the same type of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation you provided, the difference lays on the response body each method returns. It is stated that:

[templates.launch:](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch) *if successful, the response body contains an instance of LaunchTemplateResponse.*

[templates.create:](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/create) *if successful, the response body contains a newly created instance of Job.*

I hope this helps.